# Xsl 1.0 Group by lower case

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Is there a way to group by case-insensitive values.
I have a XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<doc>
  <Item id="12" type="data" value="Apple" /> 
  <Item id="13" type="data" value="apple" /> 
  <Item id="14" type="data" value="APPLE" /> 
  <Item id="11" type="data" value="car" /> 
  <Item id="10" type="data" value="CAR" /> 
  <Item id="9" type="data" value="Car" /> 
  <Item id="8" type="data" value="Tomato" /> 
  <Item id="7" type="data" value="tomato" /> 
  <Item id="6" type="data" value="TOMATO" /> 
  <Item id="24" type="data" value="TOMATOES" /> 
  <Item id="31" type="data" value="peach" /> 
  <Item id="28" type="data" value="peach" /> 
  <Item id="56" type="data" value="peach" /> 
  <Item id="62" type="data" value="Peach" /> 
  <Item id="78" type="data" value="PEACH" /> 
</doc>
```

I would like an output like:

- apple: 3
- car: 3
- tomato: 3
- tomatoes: 1
- peach: 5

I was trying to apply such stylesheet but it doesn't work:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="tag" match="*" use="translate(@Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
  <xsl:template match="doc">
   <html>
    <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
   <ul>
    <xsl:for-each select="*[count(. | key('tag', translate(@Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1]) = 1]" >
   <xsl:sort select="translate(@Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
   <li>
     <xsl:variable name="cv" select="translate(@Value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
     <xsl:value-of select="count(*[$cv=current()/@Value]/@Id)"/>
   </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </ul>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should I have to convert every node in lowercase and then group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would restrict the `key` to `Item` elements and then make sure the Muenchian grouping and sorting is done in the right template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="uc" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="lc" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

  <xsl:key name="tag" match="Item" use="translate(@value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
   <html>
    <body>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
   </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc">
      <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('tag', translate(@value, $uc, $lc))[1])]">
              <xsl:sort select="translate(@value, $uc, $lc)"/>
          </xsl:apply-templates>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Item">
   <li>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(@value, $uc, $lc), ': ', count(key('tag', translate(@value, $uc, $lc))))"/>
   </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the result is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <ul>
         <li>apple: 3</li>
         <li>car: 3</li>
         <li>peach: 5</li>
         <li>tomato: 3</li>
         <li>tomatoes: 1</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

then, I am not sure why your post has `peach` as the last item.

Comment: Good! Thanks. Peach at the last item because items are not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="tag" match="Item" use="translate(@value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>

<xsl:template match="/doc">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:for-each select="Item[count(. | key('tag', translate(@value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))[1]) = 1]" >
                    <li>
                         <xsl:variable name="cv" select="translate(@value,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($cv, ': ', count(key('tag', $cv)))"/>
                    </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </ul>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note: as you have noticed, XML is case sensitive - `@Value` does no match an attribute named `value`.